# Как создать шаблон класса в .h .cpp файлах?

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

Пишу Vector3, который хранит переменные X Y Z типа T. Написал вот такой header файл:

```
//3 diserminal vector
#ifndef VOXELENGINE_VECTOR3_H
#define VOXELENGINE_VECTOR3_H

template<class T>
class Vector3 {
public:
    T X;
    T Y;
    T Z;
    Vector3(T X, T Y, T Z);
    ~Vector3();
};


#endif //VOXELENGINE_VECTOR3_H
```

Но как теперь реализовать этот шаблон класса в .cpp файле?
Вот так не получается:

```
#include "Vector3.h"
Vector3::Vector3(T X, T Y, T Z){
    Vector3::X = X;
    Vector3::Y = Y;
    Vector3::Z = Z;
}
```

Ошибки:
неизвестный тип 'T'
Vector3 не является классом, namrspace или enumenartion

Как мне создать .cpp файл для шаблона класса? Или шаблоны вообще нельзя писать в заголовочных файлах?

Comment: Не следует так делать. Всмысле выносить реализацию шаблона в cpp файл. Это не будет работать, так во время компиляции компилятор не будет знать как инстанцировать шаблон

Comment: `template<typename T>
Vector3::Vector3(T X, T Y, T Z) { ...` - но это нужно добавить в заголовочный файл.

Comment: Зачем вам понадобился тут .cpp файл? Не следует без необходимости плодить единицы трансляции.

Comment: Сама реализация вектора и задача, которая использует вектора это совсем разный код. Всё смешивать не рекомендуется. @user7860670

Comment: @AlexGlebe А зачем вы отвечаете, это же вопрос был не вам?

Comment: https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1798717.html#post9488987

Answer (score 1):

Реализация шаблонов для всех типов сразу не создаётся. Шаблонные функции должны присутствовать всегда в хедер файлах. Вот пример рабочий :

Vector3.h

```
//3 diserminal vector
#ifndef VOXELENGINE_VECTOR3_H
#define VOXELENGINE_VECTOR3_H

template<class T>
class Vector3 {
public:
    T X;
    T Y;
    T Z;
    Vector3(T X, T Y, T Z);
    // деструктор пока не надо переделывать
    // ~Vector3();
};

// реализация всегда присутствует для всех типов и
// для всех компилируемых файлов
// в более сложных ситуациях (циклических связей шаблонов)
// подключайте "Vector3-impl.h" в '.cpp' файлах
# include "Vector3-impl.h"

#endif //VOXELENGINE_VECTOR3_H
```

Vector3-impl.h

```
#ifndef VOXELENGINE_VECTOR3_IMPL_H
#define VOXELENGINE_VECTOR3_IMPL_H

// реализация шаблонов должна начинаться на слове template
// с именем типа T и типы Vector3 должны всегда с добавлением
// шаблонного типа T заключённого в угловых скобках
template  <class  T>
Vector3<T>::Vector3(T X, T Y, T Z){
    Vector3<T>::X = X;
    Vector3<T>::Y = Y;
    Vector3<T>::Z = Z;
}

# endif // VOXELENGINE_VECTOR3_IMPL_H
```

main.cpp

```
// g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Winline -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main
# include "Vector3.h"
int main  ( ) {
  Vector3 < int > v3  (1,2,3)  ;
  Vector3 < double > vd  (1,2,3)  ;
}
```

Comment: Пустой деструктор здесь вреден. Из-за него ваш класс при перемещении будет копировать поля, а не перемещать их.

Comment: Пока-что сделал так, чтобы компилировалось. Убрал вообще, не слышал, что будет какая-то разница. @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Пардон, не заметил что он и у автора был. Пример: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/z38ejMTY1

Comment: Посмотрел, то-есть при дописывании пустого деструктора мув-конструктора в `B` не стало. Мне пришлось дописывать мув конструктор индивидуально. @HolyBlackCat Ну это мелочи, вектор ещё писа'ть и писа'ть.